# How to align text/ content in angular and css?

Tags: html, css, angular

I am trying to align the text in my expand/collapse question bar below using angular. The code below is one of the HTML/ Angular snippets. There are quite a few of these code blocks which makes the picture below

```
  <mat-expansion-panel hideToggle>
  <mat-expansion-panel-header>
   <mat-panel-title>
    User Data Management
   </mat-panel-title>
  <mat-panel-description>
   What is an agent?
  </mat-panel-description>
  </mat-expansion-panel-header>
  <p>An agent is an individual hired to liaise with a user via the robot</p>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
```

CSS

```
 styles: [

  mat-panel-description {
  color: red;
  align-content: center;
 }
```

[image]

As you can see the red text is completely out of alignment even though I have aligned content to center.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

Change from `align-content:center;` to `justify-content:center;`. That'all.

Update: mat-panel-title size fits content, so you need to fix it's width:

```
mat-panel-title {
    width: 50%; //change based on your requirements
}
```

Comment: doesnt seem to work. It seemed to have pushed some of the items to the left. I've also tried align-text which also doesnt work

Comment: still nothing. your update just pushed the description closer to the title?

Comment: I've just tested in stackbllitz, take a look: 

https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-expansion-panel-rqotr3?file=app%2Fexpansion-overview-example.ts

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
mat-expansion-panel-header {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
mat-panel-description {
    width: 300px; // im using fixed width so that it will be aligned, maybe there's an other way though
    text-align: center;
}
```

Not sure if this will work, but it's worth a try.